# python, is swig recommended?

Tags: python, python-3.x, swig

I was reading that in python we can use `swig` to convert a program from c language to python and I have some questions regarding that

**a.** does that work for every code in c or only for most cases? if yes, then why don't most companies make a version of their code in python in case the original was written in c?

**b.** does it affect performance? I mean will writing my program directly in python as effective as writing it in c and then convert it to python?

Comment: Swig provides an interface layer for a C/C++ program that can then be used to auto-generate shims to python, java, c#, perl and others. It doesn't convert the program - the original C/C++ library/dll still needs to be delivered with the product. All swig does is provide a Foreign Function Interface that lets python call C/C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

`swig` is not converting C code into Python code, it builds a shared library that can be used by Python. It is a wrapper. You don't even need `swig` for that, CPython has [builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html?) [C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html). `swig` just makes it easier.

As @tdelaney said in comments, it just lets Python call C/C++ code. Offical Python interpreter itself written in C too, this is why we call it as "CPython".

And yes, it affects performance. Compiled languages like C/C++ are usually much faster than CPython. And performance is one of the reasons for calling C code from Python.